# MFMailComposeViewController.h Broken

Tags: iphone, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

After successfully implementing the MFMailComposeViewController in my app, run it in the simulator and my iPhone, where it still works fine, it just crashed.
I get 5 MFMailComposeViewController.h issues: Cannot find protocol declaration, Expected identifier or '(', etc,...

My Controller header includes:

```
MessageUI/MessageUI.h

MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h
```

and conforms to protocol:

```
@interface DetallViewController : UIViewController < UIActionSheetDelegate,
 MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

I've tried to:
1) remove and add the framework
2) Restart the device and Xcode as suggested in many posts
3) Create a separate controller to handle MFMailComposeViewController

After 3 days with this issue I'm completely stuck on this. As you can imagine, any help would be appreciate.

I would think this is a kind of reference issue since it appears whether the framework is selected or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ̀#import ̀ loop could be the cause...

Comment: How do you import the framework?

Comment: Are you importing the framework correctly? `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>`

Comment: I read it somewhere. I have tried only importing one of them but it neither solves it... Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, only #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

Comment: It's hard to tell. Can you post the error mesages you are getting?

Comment: Sure, having only #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> in the header I get: MFMailComposeViewCOntroller 1)Parse issue: Illegal interface qualifier, 2)Parse issue: Missing '@end' 3)Parse issue: Expected identifier '(' 4) Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate' 5)Parse issue: Expected a type

Comment: Delete Message Framework and then install again to remove Error.

Comment: As I said I already removed and selected again the MessageUI framework.

Answer (score 0):

Just to anybody it may help, I finally found the issue:

A missing @end in an imported header.

Thanks to everybody for the efforts.